# How to create Mysite Host location in sharepoint online using central admin?

Tags: sharepoint-online

How to create Mysite Host location in sharepoint online using central admin ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a MySite Host site, that is already provisioned for you at https://tenantName-my.sharepoint.com.

For SharePoint Online, https://tenantName-admin.sharepoint.com is called the *SharePoint* admin center, not *central* admin. That will be important to understand when looking at SPO administration documentation.